# How to prevent users from making meaningless edits

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/q/463/9208) was raised about a year ago, but it seems to have gotten worse again lately.

A handful of users are making some really meaningless edits such as; formatting single words, removing oxford commas, and replacing text with similar words that don't change the meaning at all ('when' to 'for', for example)

Is there a way to prevent or discourage this type of behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way I've found to discourage trivial edits is to reject them with the reason, "No improvement whatsoever"

I've been doing this for trivial edits that don't do anything to improve the readability of the item that was edited.

The trivial edits I accept are the ones that clean up format and make the item easier to read.

Comment: Indeed, I measure triviality on the impact on the post, not on the number of characters for the same reasons I don't measure programmer productivity in lines of code.